# Embedding openai api, ratelimit error short text

Tags: python, embedding, openai-api

Does anyone have any experience creating embeddings with Openai's API? I am stuck on an odd error (rate limit) on the first step from my few lines of code when I try to run openai.Embedding.create(input=short_string, model="text-embedding-ada-002 ). If anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated!

(I am sure my api key is valid and has credits, I tried multiple across 2 accounts one of them is paid)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per the rate limits documentation, you might have to wait for 48 hours for the initial limits to be lifted. The subsequent limits are much more accommodating.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to include a more appropiate delimiter for the TextSplitter.
In my case:

```
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=800, chunk_overlap=50, separator="\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this (I'll only post a snippet). If error 429 occurs (refers to Rate Limit by OpenAI), wait 60 seconds. If it occurs again, I split Batch in two and try again after 60 seconds. And so on...

```
...
    except HTTPException as http_error:
        if http_error.status_code == 429: # back off if rate limit reached
            logger.info("HTTP RATE LIMIT REACHED: {0}", str(http_error.detail))
            time.sleep(60)
            if len(documents_chunk) == 1:
                # retry the single document
                process_documents_chunk(documents_chunk, retries + 1)
            else:
                # Recursively divide and process the documents
                half = len(documents_chunk) // 2
                process_documents_chunk(documents_chunk[:half], retries + 1)
                time.sleep(60)
                process_documents_chunk(documents_chunk[half:], retries + 1)
        else:
            logger.exception("HTTP ERROR: {0}", str(http_error.detail))
            raise
...
```